# Can MSBuild ItemGroup's be chunked?

Tags: msbuild

I've got an ItemGroup that includes source files from my project:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <SourceFiles Include=".\**\*.h;.\**\*.cpp"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

There are a few hundred source files. I want to pass them to a command line tool in an Exec task.

If I call the command line tool individually for each file:

```
  <Exec Command="tool.exe %(SourceFiles.FullPath)" WorkingDirectory="."/>
```

Then, it runs very slowly.

If I call the command line tool and pass all of the files in one go:

```
  <Exec Command="tool.exe @(SourceFiles -> '&quot;%(FullPath)&quot;', ' ')" WorkingDirectory="."/>
```

Then, I get an error if there are too many files (I'm guessing the command line length exceeds some maximum).

Is there a way I can chunk the items so that the tool can be called a number of times, each time passing up to a maximum number of source file names to the tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any mechanism to do that with well known item metadata. What you could do is load all those paths into their own item group and write a custom task that calls the exec task. Writing a custom task is pretty simple, it can be done inline:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd722601(v=vs.100).aspx